# Max of set in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

How can I find the maximum element in a set of numbers (nat) in Isabelle. The max function doesn't work, as it is only defined to take the maximum of two elements. I have an idea of how I could implement it using a reduce like function, but I don't know how to pick one random element from a set.

Comment: Using sets if you really want to take about lists is pretty cumbersome and often makes the proofs longer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function you are looking for is called `Max`. If you are looking for basic constants the guide [What's in Main](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2012/doc/main.pdf) from the official Isabelle documentation is often useful. There is also the `find_consts` command which can be used to search for functions by type.

Comment: Just to add to this: search for constants is also available from Isabelle/jEdit's query panel (see [3.4.2, p.30](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/doc/jedit.pdf) in the Isabelle/jEdit manual). If you have an idea what your function's name—or a part of it—could be called you can write `name: <name-or-part-of-name>` to search for matching constants. Small caveat: the search is limited to the imported theories. In this case you would have to have theory `Lattices_Big` imported (which seems to be included transitively in `Main`).

Answer (score 4):

If you follow the definition of `Max` to theory `Big_Operators` in the main HOL library, you will see that it is defined like this:

```
Max = fold1 max
```

The combinator `fold1` is your "reduce like function" that works on finite sets.
See also theory `Finite_Set` and its locale `folding` for the mathematical background that is required here to fold over arbitrary sets, instead of concrete lists.